# How to decide which copy of an event should be used in asynchronous data sync?

Tags: asynchronous, network-programming, data-synchronization

I have two computers that handle certain events. It is possible that they both detect the same event at the same time. I need to decide which peer's event will be the sole event remaining (and then the peer has to do something with the event). I have no common synchronization tool available, such as a database.

The problem, as I see it, goes like this:

- Peer 1: send packet A to peer 2
- Peer 2: send packet A to peer 1
- Peer 2: incoming packet A from peer 1
- Peer 1: incoming packet A from peer 2
- ... (I'm in trouble)

How does each peer decide which packet A to keep? Both have generated the packet, both have sent it and now both also see that the other peer sent their own copy.

I need to resolve this such that one peer's packet "prevails" so that that peer can execute the necessary actions.

My current best guess:

I'm thinking to "equip" the packet with a random number. If the other peer's packet has a lower random number, it will be discarded. If number is equal to mine, the process is repeated until one of the randoms is bigger or a hiccup in network causes that the entire handshake goes through from one side only.

Does my proposed solution even work? Is there a more optimal solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the peers have IDs that are known to other peers, you could keep the packet which originates from the peer with the higher ID.

<s>If they don't have IDs, you can use their IP address instead. Convert the IP to an integer, compare them and keep the packet from the sender with the "higher" IP.</s>
**==>** This might not be reliable enough due to NAT (duplicate IPs possible).

You could use any available field of your protocol or from the underlying protocols (timestamp, MAC address, etc.).

Comment: Ha ha. And here I go inventing some randoms when I already have distinguishing IDs :p This does of course mean that ultimately it would be the same peer doing everything most of the time, but honestly I don't see how that could be harmful.

Comment: Hehe, we've all been there ;) But sharing the work is an interesting constraint. Maybe a (already existing and shared) field like task/command-Nr can be used for swapping: If command is even, bigger ID does work. If it's odd, smaller ID does.